# Postgresql create array from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like so:

```
  serial    | channel | sum   | date 
 210062912      1     0.827    2019-01-01 
 210062912      2    20.864    2019-01-01 
 210062912      3     0.000    2019-01-01 
 210062912      1     0.650    2019-01-02 
 210062912      2    29.666    2019-01-02
```

is is possible to return something as follows with postgres?

```
serial_channel |  array
210062912-1     [[2019-01-01,0.827],[2019-01-02,0.650]]
210062912-2     [[2019-01-01,20.864],[2019-01-02,29.666]]
210062912-3     [[2019-01-01,0.000]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=09bac113ad379a0bdcdc39a6b9ccb828)

The problem is your inner "array". An array can only combine value from the same type. But you are trying to combine a `numeric` type and a `date`.

You can put them into a type row and aggregate the rows:

```
SELECT
    serial || '-' || channel as serialchannel,
    array_agg(row(date, sum))
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY 1
```

Result:

```
serial_channel |  array_agg
:--------------| :----------------------------------------
210062912-1    | [(2019-01-01,0.827),(2019-01-02,0.650)]
210062912-2    | [(2019-01-01,20.864),(2019-01-02,29.666)]
210062912-3    | [(2019-01-01,0.000)]
```

---

Alternatively you can cast both values into type `text`. Then you are able to generate a text array:

```
SELECT
    serial || '-' || channel as serialchannel,
    array_agg(ARRAY[date::text, sum::text])
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY 1
```

Result:

```
serial_channel |  array_agg
:--------------| :----------------------------------------
210062912-1    | [["2019-01-01","0.827"],["2019-01-02","0.650"]]
210062912-2    | [["2019-01-01","20.864"],["2019-01-02","29.666"]]
210062912-3    | [["2019-01-01","0.000"]]
```

---

Third way is to use JSON:

```
SELECT
    serial || '-' || channel as serialchannel,
    json_agg(json_build_object('date', mydate, 'sum', mysum))
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY 1

serialchannel | json_agg                                                                          
:------------ | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
210062912-3   | [{"sum" : 0.000, "date" : "2019-01-01"}]                                          
210062912-2   | [{"sum" : 20.864, "date" : "2019-01-01"}, {"sum" : 29.666, "date" : "2019-01-02"}]
210062912-1   | [{"sum" : 0.827, "date" : "2019-01-01"}, {"sum" : 0.650, "date" : "2019-01-02"}]
```

Comment: Thank you.  That does work, but is it possible to return with the square brackets?

Comment: Showed you the three ways that came to my mind. If you really want to get array of arrays, then you'll need to cast all array elements into the same type, as described.

Comment: Awesome!
I have options
Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. If please upvote ALL answers that might be helpful. That honors the time and work the repliers invested into your problem with some internal credits. We'd appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can return a JSONB array, where the key is the date:

```sql
select concat_ws('-', "serial", channel) as serial_channel, 
       jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object("date", sum))
from the_table
group by serial_channel;
```

would return:

```
serial_channel | jsonb_agg                                       
---------------+-------------------------------------------------
210062912-3    | [{"2019-01-01": 0.000}]                         
210062912-2    | [{"2019-01-01": 20.864}, {"2019-01-02": 29.666}]
210062912-1    | [{"2019-01-01": 0.827}, {"2019-01-02": 0.650}]
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/FZS1666